# How to redirect to a "part-view" of a view file?

Tags: joomla-2.5, component, view

I have a `view` called **Vtour**. Inside **Vtour** I have these files:

```
view.html.php
index.php
/tmpl/
/tmpl/default.php
```

So `default.php` is the default `view` which loads a form that a user can select elements to download.

What I'm trying to do is: create a second view named `default2.php` inside `tmpl/`  where I will set the correct php headers for downloading.

What I can't find out is how to redirect there:
`action="com_iproperty&view=vtour"` will always redirect to `default.php`
 How can I make it redirect to default2.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you just need to add the `layout` **GET** parameter to the URL

Also you can redirect in the controller using `setRedirect()` and `JRoute`.

```
$this->setRedirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_iproperty&view=vtour&layout=default2', false), $msg);
```